# Error in building pulseaudio in yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3, yocto, bitbake, pulseaudio

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I am facing build issue while building bitbake pulseaudio.

I am using Yocto : jethro branch

I am getting a do compile error while running the command `bitbake pulseaudio`

But while building it lead to do compile error as follows I am getting an r7 error

```
/pulseaudio/6.0-r0/pulseaudio-6.0/src/pulsecore/remap_neon.c:65:1: error: r7 cannot be used in asm here
```

Is there any way i can clear this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your local.conf :

```
PACKAGECONFIG_pulseaudio += " --disable-atomic-arm-linux-helpers"
```